# 'Undo Move' feature Implementation for a 2D Array Board Game

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

'Undo Move' feature Implementation for a 2D Array Board Game

Hi all

Using an ArrayList, I am trying to implement an undo move feature whereby, a user can select an option ‘Z’, which makes possible a multi-level ‘undo’. In other words, if the user selects ‘Z’ then the previous move is undone, if he immediately selects ‘Z’ again, the move before that is undone, and so on.

I have been able to get the code to add new move objects each time a valid move ‘U’, ’D’, ’L’, ’R’ is made and to also remove the last object, each time ‘Z’ is pressed.

My question is, how do I make the player movements (coordinates) and eaten doughnuts (Boolean) rely on the last object in the ArrayList so that when ‘Z’ is pressed and the last object in the ArrayList is removed, the player movements and eaten doughnuts will now rely on the new last object in the ArrayList to create the ‘undo’ effect? Hope my question makes sense.

The ‘Z’ implementation is the last case in the switch statement in the move method.

My classes are below:

```
package secondproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int INITIAL_PLAYER_COL = 0;
    private static final int INITIAL_PLAYER_ROW = BOARD_SIZE - 1;
    private static final int HOME_COL = BOARD_SIZE - 1;
    private static final int HOME_ROW = 0;
    private static final int WALL_LENGTH = 5;
    private static final char PLAYER_CHAR = 'P';
    private static final char HOME_CHAR = 'H';
    private static final char WALL_CHAR = 'X';
    private static final char FREE_SQUARE_CHAR = '.';
    private static final char DOUGHNUT_CHAR = '@';
    private static final char UP_MOVE_CHAR = 'U';
    private static final char DOWN_MOVE_CHAR = 'D';
    private static final char LEFT_MOVE_CHAR = 'L';
    private static final char RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR = 'R';
    private static final char UNDO_MOVE_CHAR = 'Z';
    private static final char TRAIL_CHAR = 'M';

    private static char[][] board = new char[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static int playerCol = INITIAL_PLAYER_COL;
    private static int playerRow = INITIAL_PLAYER_ROW;
    private static int nbrDoughnuts = 0;
    private static int nbrMoves = 0;
    private static Random random = new Random();

    private static int lives = 1;
    private static int doughnutLives;
    private static boolean doughnutCheck;
    static ArrayList<Move> movement = new ArrayList<Move>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        setUpBoard();
        showBoard();
        String opt;
        do {
            System.out.print("Next option ?");
            opt = scan.next();
            char opt1 = opt.charAt(0);
            if (opt1 == UP_MOVE_CHAR || opt1 == DOWN_MOVE_CHAR || opt1 == LEFT_MOVE_CHAR || opt1 == RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR || opt1 == UNDO_MOVE_CHAR) {
                move(opt1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Allowed commands are: + " + UP_MOVE_CHAR + "," + DOWN_MOVE_CHAR + "," + LEFT_MOVE_CHAR + "," + RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR);
            }
            showBoard();
            System.out.println("Number of moves made = " + nbrMoves);
            System.out.println("Number of doughnuts eaten = " + nbrDoughnuts);
            System.out.println("Lives = " + lives);
        } while (board[HOME_ROW][HOME_COL] == HOME_CHAR);
        System.out.println("Thank you and goodbye");
    }

    /**
     * Set up the initial state of the board
     */
    private static void setUpBoard() {
        intialiseBoard(); // Fill the board with . characters
        //Add  the first vertical wall
        int v1StartCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
        int v1StartRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - WALL_LENGTH - 1);
        addVerticalWall(v1StartCol, v1StartRow, WALL_LENGTH);

        //Add the second vertical wall
        int v2StartCol;
        do {
            v2StartCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
        } while (v2StartCol == v1StartCol);
        int v2StartRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - WALL_LENGTH - 1);
        addVerticalWall(v2StartCol, v2StartRow, WALL_LENGTH);

        //Add the horizontal wall
        int h1StartRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
        int h1StartCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - WALL_LENGTH - 1);
        addHorizontalWall(h1StartCol, h1StartRow, WALL_LENGTH);

        //Add the dougnuts
        int nbrDoughnutsAdded = 0;
        while (nbrDoughnutsAdded < 5) {
            int dRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
            int dCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
            if (board[dRow][dCol] == FREE_SQUARE_CHAR) {
                board[dRow][dCol] = DOUGHNUT_CHAR;
                nbrDoughnutsAdded++;
            }
        }

        //Add the player and the home square
        board[playerRow][playerCol] = PLAYER_CHAR;
        board[HOME_ROW][HOME_COL] = HOME_CHAR;
    }

    /**
     * Add a vertical wall to the board
     *
     * @param startCol Column on which wall is situated
     * @param startRow Row on which top of wall is situated
     * @param length Number of squares occupied by wall
     */
    private static void addVerticalWall(int startCol, int startRow, int length) {
        for (int row = startRow; row < startRow + length; row++) {
            board[row][startCol] = WALL_CHAR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a horizontal wall to the board
     *
     * @param startCol Column on which leftmost end of wall is situated
     * @param startRow Row on which wall is situated
     * @param length Number of squares occupied by wall
     */
    private static void addHorizontalWall(int startCol, int startRow, int length) {
        for (int col = startCol; col < startCol + length; col++) {
            board[startRow][col] = WALL_CHAR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the board
     */
    private static void showBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fill the board with FREE_SQUARE_CHAR characters.
     */
    private static void intialiseBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                board[row][col] = FREE_SQUARE_CHAR;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Move the player
     *
     * @param moveChar Character indicating the move to be made
     */
    private static void move(char moveChar) {
        int newCol = playerCol;
        int newRow = playerRow;

        switch (moveChar) {
            case UP_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newRow--;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newRow = newRow - number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case DOWN_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newRow++;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    squareNumberPrompt();
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newRow = newRow + number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case LEFT_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newCol--;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    squareNumberPrompt();
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newCol = newCol - number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newCol++;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    squareNumberPrompt();
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newCol = newCol + number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case UNDO_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (movement.size() >= 1) {
                    movement.remove(movement.size() - 1);
                    System.out.println("The decreasing  size of the arraylist is now " + movement.size());
                } else if (movement.size() < 1) {
                    System.out.println("There is no move to be undone!");
                }
                break;
        }
        if (newRow < 0 || newRow >= BOARD_SIZE || newCol < 0 || newCol >= BOARD_SIZE) {
            System.out.println("Sorry that move takes you off the board!");
        } else {
            char dest = board[newRow][newCol];
            if (dest == WALL_CHAR) {
                System.out.println("Sorry you landed on a wall!");
            } else {
                nbrMoves++;
                if (dest == DOUGHNUT_CHAR) {
                    doughnutCheck = true;
                    nbrDoughnuts++;
                    doughnutLives++;
                    lives = (doughnutLives + 1);
                }
                board[playerRow][playerCol] = FREE_SQUARE_CHAR;
                playerCol = newCol;
                playerRow = newRow;
                board[playerRow][playerCol] = PLAYER_CHAR;
            }
        }
        if (moveChar == UP_MOVE_CHAR || moveChar == DOWN_MOVE_CHAR || moveChar == LEFT_MOVE_CHAR || moveChar == RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR) {
            movement.add(new Move(playerCol, playerRow, newCol, newRow, doughnutCheck));
            System.out.println("The increasing  size of the arraylist is now " + movement.size());
        }
    }

    public static void squareNumberPrompt() {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of squares to be moved");
    }

    public static void checkLives() {
        System.out.println("Invalid number! The number must be"
                + " equal to or less than the number of lives you have");
    }
}





package secondproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Move {

    private static int pColumn;
    private static int pRow;
    private static int nCol;
    private static int nRow;
    private static boolean dCheck;

    public Move(int playerCol, int playerRow, int newCol, int newRow, boolean doughnutCheck) {
        pColumn = playerCol;
        pRow = playerRow;
        nCol = newCol;
        nRow = newRow;
        dCheck = doughnutCheck;
    }

    public int getFromCol() {
        return pColumn;
    }

    public int getFromRow() {
        return pRow;
    }

    public int getToCol() {
        return nCol;
    }

    public int getToRow() {
        return nRow;
    }

    public boolean isDoughnutEaten() {
        return dCheck;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep a stack of coordinates. Push the coordinates into the stack whenever it's not an undo move. Pop from the stack when it's an undo move.

Comment: either you keep a list of every donut eaten during one move or you need to recreate the game from scratch, starting with move 1. It's also possible to use a data structure that remembers where the player already was and if an undo removes one of those points a donut is placed there again. although that might get complicated if the player visits a tile more than once but then you could just remember the count.

Comment: Unless of course every tile has a donut on it and can only be visited once then you actually only need to know where you went so you can replace the donut there... i doubt that's how it is though.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet Sorry, I don’t quite follow as I am new to Java, can you please elaborate programmatically, no matter how brief?

Comment: @Mark The game’s got only five doughnuts. Your first suggestion about doughnuts lists sounds smart, would you be kind enough to expand on it please?

Comment: @ChizzyMeka You can take a look to [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). For future it gives you possibility to implement undo for each command implementation. For sure it would require change the approach to do the code "more" OOP, but anyway the subject is worth to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking a bit closer at your code, you basically already have everything you need for that undo in place.
Maybe even a bit too much :D You don't actually need from and to positions. only the position the move put you into would suffice.

So when you press Z, your code should look somewhat like this:

```
Move lastMove = movement.remove(movement.size() - 1);
playerCol = movement.get(movement.size() - 1).getToCol();
playerRow = movement.get(movement.size() - 1).getToRow();
board[playerRow][playerCol] = PLAYER_CHAR;
if (lastMove.isDoughnutEaten()) {
    int dCol = lastMove.getToCol();
    int dRow = lastMove.getToRow();
    board[dRow][dCol] = DOUGHNUT_CHAR;
    nbrDoughnutsAdded--;
}
```

Right now, you could read the new player position from the pColumn and pRow values of lastMove, but as I said, that's kind of overkill because you can read it from the new last element of the list anyway.

Keep in mind that you still need to catch special cases (like when you undo the very first move. In this case, you'd need to read the former player position from your static variables that define the starting point instead of the last element of the list (that won't exist anymore))

Comment: Yes, I believe I have implemented the mechanism. My confusion lies in how to code the reverting to the last position and doughnut state. I just cannot get my head around it.

Comment: I edited the code example a little I hope I didn't miss anything but that's basically how to code the reverting.